# Syntax for "Capturing" returned value of a Perl script from batch?

Tags: perl, batch-file, return

I'd like to store a returned value of perl in batch. How do I accomplish this?

```
Batch Code:
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('perl.exe c:\TestProp1noRefCases.pl 859') DO set lineCase=%%I 
echo !lineCase! ::Nothing is outputted

Perl Code:
use strict;
use warnings;
sub main1;

my $arg1 =shift;
main1($arg1);
exit;
sub main1
{
            #Returns 1,2,3 Depending on testNum passed
            my @gp1= (829,845,851,859,864,867);
            my @gp2= (861,863,865);
            # my @gp4= (826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883);
    # my @gp3= (877-882,884);
            my $val1=1;
            my $val2=2;
            my $val3=3;
            my $val4=4;

            if((grep /^$arg1$/,@gp1) || ($arg1 >=822 && $arg1<=824))
            {     
                            # print "$val1\n";
                            return $val1;

            } elsif ((grep /^$arg1$/,@gp2) || ($arg1>=855 && $arg1<=858))
            {
            #print "$val2\n";
                            return $val2;
            } elsif (($arg1==884) || ($arg1>=877 && $arg1<=882))
            {
            #print "$val3\n";
                            return $val3;
            } else
            {
                #print "$val4\n";
                            return $val4;

            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually print a value to be captured. Change

```
main1($arg1);
```

to

```
print main1($arg1);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `echo !lineCase!`. If that doesn't work, you can use `echo %lineCase%`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not exiting with a return value.

Instead of

```
main1($arg1);
exit;
```

Try:

```
my $result = main1($arg1);
exit $result;
```

or:

```
exit main1($arg1);
```

and then examine `%ERRORLEVEL%` in your batch.

```
perl.exe c:\TestProp1noRefCases.pl 859
set lineCase=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

Edit: Note, this only works for small unsigned integers, like the `$val1..$val4` in your example.